# Page can be dragged down in iPhone - Framework7 Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, html-framework-7

I use Framework7 and Cordova wrapper for my IOS app and I need to disable dragging effect in my content.

I have tried disabling pull-to-refresh effect from Cordova side but still the content is draggable and returns original position when release.

Below are not giving expected results

```
 <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
 <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

My app is not refreshing when drag down, so I guess it is nothing to do with pull-to-refresh feature. I need to make sure only scrolling works when dragging.

[image]

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not exact solution, but as a workaround I added a thinner outer most div with no scroll and added the contents as an inner div. Then no dragging in inner scrolling content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also searching for a solution and found one.

1. Open your project in XCode.
2. At the end of CDVWKWebViewEngine.m, add:

> ```
> @implementation UIScrollView (NoBounce)
> - (void)didMoveToWindow {
>    [super didMoveToWindow];
>    self.bounces = NO;
> }
> @end
> ```

Credits: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/113#issuecomment-391996908